# Unique roots in a neighborhood of a Lie group's identity (Stillwell, Naive Lie Theory, Problem 7.4.1)

Tags: lie-groups

I'm working my way through Stillwell's *Naive Lie Theory*, and feel like I'm missing something simple with problem 7.4.1, which reads:

> Show that each $A \in  N_\delta (\mathbf 1)$ has a unique *n*th  root for $n=1,2,3,...$.

Here, $N_\delta (\mathbf 1)$ is a neighborhood of the identify element of a Lie group $G$ that is mapped into the tangent space of $G$ by $\log$. I assume he means that there is a unique root *in* $N_\delta (\mathbf 1)$

But if we just consider $U(1)$, it seems like whatever neighborhood of $\mathbf 1$ I choose, for large enough $n$ there will be multiple roots of unity in the neighborhood. What am I missing here?

Edit:

Based on the discussion with @Alp, it does seem like the phrasing of the question is a bit off. Here's a rewrite that seems to capture the intent:

> Show that for each $n\in \mathbb Z^+$ there exists a neighborhood $N_{\delta_n}(\mathbf 1)$ such that each $A\in N_{\delta_n}(\mathbf 1)$ has a unique $n$th root in $N_{\delta_n}(\mathbf 1)$.

Comment: It seems $\delta$ is meant to work for one $n$ (or finitely many $n$'s) at a time.

Comment: That's a thought. Maybe he also just didn't mean to include "unique".

Comment: I think uniqueness is the important point in this exercise, considering the next exercise in the book, but you may be right.

Comment: That's true. My rephrasing, then, is: Show that for each $n\in \mathbb Z^+$ there is a neighborhood $N_n(\mathbf 1)$ such that each $A\in N_n$ has a unique $n$th root in $N_n(\mathbf 1)$.

Comment: It might be better to write $\forall n, \exists \delta_n: N_{\delta_n}(1)$... to be in accordance with the book's notation.

Comment: Fair. And thanks!